# Is there a way to auto-modify a GCP instance? (with Ansible)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automation, ansible, cloud, virtual-machine

I'm wondering if there is a way to auto-modify a GCP instance (RAM, disks, number of vCPUs) **without** creating a new Virtual Machine. For example, auto-adding 2 GB of RAM in a machine that has reached 90% of its memory capacity, or adding storage on an existing disk that is nearly full...

I have seen that Ansible has features to create new GCP instances and disks, but nothing about managing RAM or vCPUs on a Virtual Machine.

Do you guys have any suggestions about how I could proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to stop the instance and then you can add RAM/disks/etc. There is no need to create a new VM for that.

Comment: So Google SDK is clearly enough for automation?

Comment: Yes, you could also do it in the command line to create a script that can set the cpu,etc.